# Which version of MVC I can integrate with Sitecore v7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7

I have installed Sitecore version 7.0 and I'm creating new sitecore project in MVC.
So my question is that can I integrate MVC latest version i.e. MVC 4/5 with sitecore v7.0

Should I implement MVC or Web form for developing website in Sitecore v7.0.
Which one is best for future prospective.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore 7.0 only supports MVC 4 out of the box. There are several blog posts on how to use MVC 5 on Sitecore 7 or Sitecore 7.1 (i.e. [here](http://kamsar.net/index.php/2013/12/using-mvc-5-with-sitecore-7-1/)), but I would recommend to use MVC 4 with Sitecore 7.0. Sitecore 7.2 now supports MVC 5.1.

So that's primary opinion based. But for future prospective I think it's better to use MVC, because more and more resources will come to MVC.